# Cannot run script inside container without sudo if launched using docker compose, but can run it with docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container that is based on 2 other layers: fundamental base image -> intermediate base image -> user image.

In the fundamental layer, I have installed an SDK library that I want to use in the user image. The library was installed as a `root` user using the installation script by SDK provider.

In the user image, when launching the container as follows:

```
docker run --rm -it --entrypoint bash -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -h $HOSTNAME user_image:latest
```

I am able to run a script provided by SDK simply by executing it. However, when I launch the same container using *docker compose up*, I get segfaults from running the same script, unless script is run with **sudo**

#### My docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
    user_image:
        image: user_image:latest
        command: bash -c "roscore"
        container_name: my_stack
        user: user
        privileged: true
        stdin_open: true
        tty: false
        network_mode: "host"
        environment:
            - DISPLAY=${DISPLAY}
```

#### Running the script

The script I am trying to run is a C++ binary that has been compiled as part of SDK.
When looking at permissions of the binary file, I see the following:

`-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 721864 Mar 22 15:45 StViewer*` 
The `user` user belongs to `sudo` group:

```
uid=1000(user) gid=1000(user) groups=1000(user),27(sudo),1001(pcap)
```

to my understanding, I should not have problem executing the script without typing **sudo**, since it is given permission to execute this file.

However, it works only if I launch the container using `docker run`, not with `docker compose up`. Launching container with `docker compose up` requires the use of **sudo** despite having priveleges and being in the sudo group.

What is the source of this behavior? How can I make the user run the script without having to enter **sudo** if container is launched with `docker compose up`?

### UPD 1

It seems that removing `network_mode: "host"` fixes the problem and allows me to run it without sudo. But then I cannot see the devices on host. Will investigate what is wrong there.

Comment: When you run it using `docker run`, the container runs as root and has full access. When you run it from compose, you set the user to 'user' which doesn't have full access. To make them equivalent, you can remove the `user` in the compose file. Then it'll run as root.

Comment: You say the program produces a segmentation fault.  Have you done things like opening up a core dump in a debugger to get a stack trace, or added instrumentation into the application to see where it is crashing?  It might be easier to do this debugging on the host system without involving Docker it all (with the volume mounts and options you have, it's not clear how much of the core Docker isolation features you're actually using).

Comment: @HansKilian My `user_image:latest` was created with user `user`, and when entering the container with `docker run`, it runs the container with the `user`, not root access.

Comment: @sejego OK. The specification of the user was just a difference I spotted between the two ways you run the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze I got my hands on the core dumps, it seems that some function that has to update network socket interfaces is failing. I have contacted the SDK provider to explain the purpose of the functions, to better understand where the problem may be on my side. Thank you once again for suggestion!